# Finding what Branch ends with a given commit's SHA1, while not fetching branches locally

Tags: git, jenkins, branch, pull-request

I am trying to determine what branch is the source of a pull request.

When launching a Jenkins Job, I have access to the pull request last commit SHA1.
From there i need to know which branch has the same commit SHA1.

Since During the Job not all branches are being fetched, I would like to keep it that way.

My question is:

How can I get the name of the remote branch that ends with a given commit's SHA1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Git is new enough (2.7.0 or later), use `git branch --points-at`.  Unless you have a mirror clone you will need to be using `-r` here as well, to look at remote-tracking names rather than branch names.  You will also need to `git fetch` all names.  You can use a shallow fetch, if you're concerned with the number of commits and other objects that this will bring in.

Note that this won't help if new commits were added since the pull request, such that the name now points to commit that, at the time of the commit, was only in the future.  It also cannot disambiguate cases where multiple branch names point at the *same* commit, and these are not uncommon.

You can achieve all of these same things using the names and hash IDs that spill out of `git ls-remote`, but that requires writing a bit of code, rather than just using `git branch --points-at`.  Run `git ls-remote` to see what it prints (all it does is print some other Git's references and hash IDs, as obtained by what would be the first step of `git fetch` if you ran `git fetch`).

Ultimately, any answers you get at all are suspect at best.  This is probably the wrong way to do whatever it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am well aware that this is something UNCLEAN, the best way to implement this is by creating a jenkins plugin that creates pull requests at server side and keeps the branch name there.
However I am looking for a work-around. Your answer seems to me the best I can get here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find this with

```
 git branch --contains <commit>
```

This will give you a list of local branches

or

```
 git branch -r --contains <commit>
```

This will give you a list remote tracking branches

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
My issue with git branch is that it lists all the branches that conatin a given commit sha1.
I was actually looking for something that only lists branches ending with the given commit's SHA1